# CSS expand border-bottom with transition on hover

Tags: css

I am trying to get the following transition of the h1 tag working for the border-bottom of the div. Here's what I've set up for the h1 tag:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
 
}

h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
 content: '';
 height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;  
}

h1:hover:after {
 width: 100%;
  margin-left: -135px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 300px">
  <h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
</div>
```

How do I make this work for the div border bottom? Here's what I came up with, and I see why it would't work (among other things the 'width' doesn't work for the border), but I can't figure out how to solve it.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  left: 50%;
 content: '';
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div:hover:after {
 width: 300px;
  margin-left: -135px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 300px">
  <h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have defined `div:hover` instead of  `div:after`.

Comment: You cannot animate the border-bottom property like that, but you can create and animate something that looks like a border bottom - see this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/emNjGo

Comment: thanks connexo, just edited it

Comment: D-Money, that's the h1 example I gave. It must be possible to animate a border.

Comment: @tealowpillow it is not animating the actual property 'border bottom', in your example it is animating a pseudo 'after' element with a background colour set to blue and a height set to mimic a border. Check out the codepen I linked above, it's the pseudo elements that are animating, not the actual border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this

```
div{
position:fixed;}
```

and remove margin-left it will work

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

div{
position:fixed;}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
 content: '';
 height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;  
}

div:hover:after {
 width: 100%;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 300px">
  <h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  color: #666;
  margin: 0;
}

div::after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  content: ' ';
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: width 0.5s linear;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div:hover::after {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 300px">
  <h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it for the div border not for h1 (it already works for h1 as you can see in my code snippet)

Comment: The same principles apply but fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
div {
  position: relative;<---Added
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;<----Added
  //more code....
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

div:hover:after{
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 300px">
  <h1>CSS IS AWESOME</h1>
</div>
```